# jQuery Easing Plugin not working

Tags: jquery, animation, easing

Can't seem to get this jQuery easing plugin to work!  I saw it on http://easings.net/ and I have a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/ with my code

I'm new to this please help!

`$("#coolDiv").animate({'top':'-300px'},600,'easeOutBack',function(){
                            $(this).css({'top':'310px'});`

Comment: See if this works for you http://jsfiddle.net/Pzzhx/

Comment: i tested the example from @Fabi and it work fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [jQuery easing plugin](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js) should work:

```
#coolDiv {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

<div id="coolDiv">cool</div>

var left = $('#coolDiv').offset().left;

$("#coolDiv").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"0px"}, { duration: 1500, easing: "easeOutBack" });
```

Note that the main difference is adding { duration: 1500, easing: "easeOutBack" } to the animate function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzzhx/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked great! Just wondering what the left:left means  - For my purposes I changed the code to slide in from the top and also I will have 3 animations so I was changing the variables and the first reference to 'left' in the section of code left:left seems useless.  In the fiddle you will see I replaced this with 'duck' and it worked - just wondering.... http://jsfiddle.net/Pzzhx/1/

Comment: you're getting the offset left of the #coolDiv.. and animate it to the left from that position.. try alert(left) right after var left and youll see the starting value.. so it reads move block from N px to  left:0px, duration 1500 and easing effect "easeOutBack"... glad it worked, if you could please accept it so I can increase my reputation...thanks

Comment: Accpeted - but I still don't understand what the variable where I currently use 'duck' means / does. Thoughts?

Comment: you know, youre right. In this case makes no sense to have it there since youre not adding anything to it (and you already set TOP in your css). But in the previous code, you have not set the LEFT offset, so you need to get it and set it on the css. Try removing the css function and see it goes nowhere..